# Store and retrieve List in List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to know if there are more efficient way to do this.
I am trying to call List from the List

```
public class GetL{
public List getList(){
   List mainList = new ArrayList();
   List subList = new ArrayList();
   List subList2 = new ArrayList();

   subList.add("one");
   subList.add("two");
   mainList.add(subList);

   subList2.add("three");
   subList2.add("four");
   mainList.add(subList2);

   return mainList;
}
}
```

and I would call it like this.

```
GetL getL = new GetL();
List tempList = getL.getList();
tempList.get(0);
tempList.get(1);
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?
One of the biggest reason that I don't like this way is that I have to create so many different "List"

**edit:**
The biggest problem for me is that I am trying to query data from DB (ie id, age, name)and it can be well over 100 sets. And I cannot dynamically declare many List and store into "mainList"

My original design was using while loop and clear the list.

```
while( something ){
   subList.add(something);
   subList.add(something2);
   mainList.add(subList);
   subList.clear();
}
```

I didn't know clear() list also clear the stored value in mainList...

Comment: The `get` method in the `ArrayList` class take only O(1). In your case you would have to do a `get` twice if you know the index of the element you are looking for. I do not think this is bad.

Comment: It's really hard to give advice based on your example: it doesn't provide any context and really doesn't make any sense.  I think we'll have more success if you try to provide a simple explanation of what you're trying to achieve.  If you do that, we can probably make some good suggestions.

Comment: @jahroy Sorry for the messy code. I am querying data from DB (ie id, age, name)and it can be well over 100 sets. And I cannot dynamically declare that many List and store into "mainList"

Comment: What are you using to interact with the database?  JDBC?  JPA?  Presumeably your response from the database involves either a ResultSet or a List of some sort.  You should be iterating over the results to build your list (or list of lists).  If you're using JPA, your entities should be handling much of this automatically.

Comment: Please provide a small example of how you query the database, receive the results, and then attempt to do something with them.  We still don't know enough about what you're trying to do to provide any helpful advice.  We have no idea why you need to build lists of lists, no idea how you're trying to do it, and no idea what you're trying to do with the list of lists.  Providing example code with no meaning or context does not help (for example: your while loop example provides zero useful information).

Comment: However... You should just create a new List inside of your while loop.  You can't re-use the same list object if you want multiple different lists.  As soon as you call _subList.clear()_ it will clear the list you just added to main list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
/** 
 *  Returns a list of lists containing Foo objects.
 */

public List<List<Foo>> getListOfLists() {
    ResultSet rs = // get data from database...
    List<List<Foo>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<Foo>>();
    for (Row r : rs) {
        List<Foo> subList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        for (Foo f : r.getFooList()) {
            subList.add(f);
        }
        mainList.add(subList);
    }
    return mainList;
}
```

The above code assumes that your database query returns a ResultSet.

It also assumes that each row from the ResultSet has a method that returns a list of Foo objects.

Each sub-list contains objects of type Foo (which you can replace with whatever class you're using).

For a more helpful answer, please try to share some example code that shows what you're trying to do.

Right now we can only guess at what you're after...